# Angular / ng-bootstrap datetime format

Tags: html, angular, ng-bootstrap

I need help on how to get ng-bootstrap datetimepicker, instead of just datepicker.

This [link](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/datepicker/overview) shows datepicker separate and timepicker separate but I want a datetimepicker instead. Here is the format that want: **2019-09-10 12:54:30.963852**.

Is there a way to get that format using ng-bootstrap?

Below is HTML example for ng-bootstrap datepicker:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label>Date:</label> <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="yyyy-mm-dd" ngbDatepicker #d="ngbDatepicker"**strong text** required>
    <button (click)="d.toggle()"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></i></button>
</div>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With normal Bootstrap you can specify the format:

```
format: 'Y-M-D hh:mm:ss:SSSSSS'
```

See this example: https://jsfiddle.net/6v8zs7a5/2/

Something like this should work with ng-bootstrap as well.

Comment: It's angular 8 I am trying to learn, did you know how to implement this format in angular component.ts file?

Comment: @Pleasure not really. Actually I was hoping this format could be used there like it can be used in Bootstrap datetimepicker. If not, then please let me know and I will remove my answer.